# Finding MySQL status statistics in Java App

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

In my Java app, I want to query the MySQL status statistics.  I'm adding some simple monitoring (mostly writing alerts when certain settings reach certain thresholds).

In any case, I can't get it working using standard JDBC code.  I want something like this:

```
ResultSet s = DBUtil.executeQuery("SHOW STATUS LIKE '%conn%'");
```

But this isn't working from what I see in the debugger.  Any solutions?

Comment: What do you mean "can't get it working?" Do you get exceptions or just wrong data? If it is wrong data, take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/show-status.html You may need to add the `GLOBAL`  keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the link to the documentation.  It helped clear up some confusion.

For the record, here's how I navigated the ResultSet properly to find the values I wanted...

```
            String sql = "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%conn%'";
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try
            {
                rs = DBUtil.executeQuery(stmt, sql);
                while (rs != null && rs.next())
                {
                    if (StringUtils.equals(rs.getString(1), "Max_used_connections"))
                        return rs.getString(2);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
```